# How to set background opacity and border opacity in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox"/>
```

The `TextBox` in code behind has two booleans:

```
 myTextBox.Background.Opacity = 0;
 myTextBox.BorderBrush.Opacity = 0;
```

Now this is all good and dandy, but how do I set these two properties in XAML?

Btw, setting:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Background="#00FFFFFF"/>
```

Does not effect the `Opacity` property. I'd like to specifically set that opacity property in XAML.

Answer (score 83):

You want to do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="foo bar">
    <TextBlock.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Azure" Opacity="0.5" />
    </TextBlock.Background>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot today! This is the solution if you need a different opacity for the foreground and the background.

Answer (score 22):

Opacity in XAML is defined as a double, not an HTML color triplet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx

You'll want to set it like this:

```
<TextBlock Opacity="0" />
```

You can also use a brush to set it:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF295564" Opacity="0.3"/>
```

...and then set the background property to your brush.

Comment: this is the opacity of the contol, I'm referring the opacity of the background or the border

Comment: @foreyez. The second option is setting the opacity for the Brush just as you are programmatically through myTextBox.Background.Opacity.

Comment: Exactly, using a brush allows you to set either the border opacity or the background.

Comment: Voted down because zi3guw provided a full XAML example, and opacity alone in the element itself would make the whole element, that is foreground and background, transparent.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know when or if this was changed in the past, but at least with WPF 4.5 it's perfectly fine to use 8-digit-hex-color-codes:

```
<Element Background="#19ff0000"/> // background will be red with an alpha of 10%
```

The first two digits specify the alpha channel, with `00` (0) beeing fully transparent and `FF` (255) beeing fully opaque.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a transparent background in XAML there is a Transparent preset:

```
<Border Background="Transparent"/>
```